# Three.js Multiple Materials in Plane Geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to use a single plane to show multiple materials. I am currently using the MultiMaterial with the materials I plan to use inside of (textured).

The issue I am having is that the materials I use seem to get split across the entire plane into little chunks for each face. However I would like to have a material cover a 1 / n amount of the plane/mesh.

My current code (shortened):

```
var splitX = 2;
var splitY = 2;
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(800, 800, splitX, splitY);
var materials = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: preloaded texture..., side: THREE.DoubleSide
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.DoubleSide
    })
];

// set a single square inside the plane to the desired textured material
geometry.faces[0].materialIndex = 0;
geometry.faces[1].materialIndex = 0;

// set the other squares inside the plane to use the coloured material
for(var i = 1; i < geometry.faces.length / 2; i++) {
    geometry.faces[i * 2].materialIndex = 1;
    geometry.faces[i * 2 + 1].materialIndex = 1;    
}

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials));
scene.add(mesh);
```

The output: http://prnt.sc/e8un2a

I marked each corner of the texture to see whether it would show the entire texture in the 2 faces I specified and it did not. Any help would be appreciated to resolve this! :)

Comment: Can you simply split the plane in n parts?

Comment: @PatriciaBeier I can create a geometry that splits the plane, but I would like the texture to be fully inside a part of the plane instead of split out over the whole plane.

Comment: It would depend on your needs, but one option may be to combine the textures in a canvas before adding to a single material. Example combining 2 images into a single texture and adding it to a single material.map [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/e6rbt3r4/)

Comment: Could this be a help? https://www.solutiondesign.com/blog/-/blogs/webgl-and-three-js-texture-mappi-1/

Comment: You can use this pattern: `texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; texture.offset.set( 0, 0 ); texture.repeat.set( 2, 2 );`

Comment: @WestLangley Yes I could do that however if I were to use the texture on it's own individual plane issues could arise with that. I'm unsure if I should clone the initial texture set the repeat and use the texture per plane.